# Performance issue when using random generator inside a class

Tags: c++, performance, random, boost

My aim is to create a wrapper around Boost uniform real distribution with Mersenne Twister in order to make it available in a library. So I created a basic class like this:

```
class mt19937
{
protected:
   boost::random::mt19937 gen_;
   boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<double> real_;
public:
   mt19937(unsigned long s = 5489UL) : gen_(s), real_(0., 1.) {};
   double get() { return real_(gen_); };
};
```

Running a performance test though, I found out that my class is much slower than a direct call to Boost ojects. In fact, the following code which samples 10 billions of numbers, takes on my machine 30s:

```
constexpr unsigned long seed = 5489UL;
constexpr size_t iter = 100000;
double x = 0.;

boost::random::mt19937 gen(seed);
boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<double> real(0., 1.);

for (size_t i = 0; i < iter; ++i)
   for (size_t j = 0; j < iter; ++j)
      x = real(gen);
```

The class `mt19937` described above, with the following code, takes around 70s:

```
mt19937 stduniform(seed);

for (size_t i = 0; i < iter; ++i)
   for (size_t j = 0; j < iter; ++j)
      x = stduniform.get();
```

Looking at assembler in Windows, in the first case the code executed for `x = real(gen)` is the following, which seems to me just the call to `boost::random::detail::generate_uniform_real` and the assignment to `x`:

```
00007FF6D14639F0  movzx       r9d,byte ptr [r15]  
00007FF6D14639F4  lea         rcx,[gen]  
00007FF6D14639F9  movaps      xmm2,xmm7  
00007FF6D14639FC  movaps      xmm1,xmm8  
00007FF6D1463A00  call        boost::random::detail::generate_uniform_real<boost::random::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int,32,624,397,31,2567483615,11,4294967295,7,2636928640,15,4022730752,18,1812433253>,double> (07FF6D146141Ah)
```

With the function `get()` I see the following istructions - it seems to perform some operations on registers that I cannot explain and a jump:

```
00007FF6D1463B61  movsd       xmm3,mmword ptr [rbp+900h]  
00007FF6D1463B69  lea         rcx,[stduniform]  
00007FF6D1463B6E  movsd       xmm4,mmword ptr [rbp+8F8h]  
00007FF6D1463B76  movaps      xmm2,xmm3  
00007FF6D1463B79  mulsd       xmm2,xmm6  
00007FF6D1463B7D  movaps      xmm1,xmm4  
00007FF6D1463B80  mulsd       xmm1,xmm6  
00007FF6D1463B84  movaps      xmm0,xmm2  
00007FF6D1463B87  subsd       xmm0,xmm1  
00007FF6D1463B8B  comisd      xmm0,xmm7  
00007FF6D1463B8F  jbe         main+2F8h (07FF6D1463B98h)  
00007FF6D1463B91  call        boost::random::detail::generate_uniform_real<boost::random::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int,32,624,397,31,2567483615,11,4294967295,7,2636928640,15,4022730752,18,1812433253>,double> (07FF6D14615D7h)  
00007FF6D1463B96  jmp         main+307h (07FF6D1463BA7h)  
00007FF6D1463B98  movzx       r9d,byte ptr [rbx]  
00007FF6D1463B9C  movaps      xmm2,xmm3  
00007FF6D1463B9F  movaps      xmm1,xmm4  
00007FF6D1463BA2  call        boost::random::detail::generate_uniform_real<boost::random::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int,32,624,397,31,2567483615,11,4294967295,7,2636928640,15,4022730752,18,1812433253>,double> (07FF6D146141Ah)
```

Is it possible that a call to a function (that should be inlined) performed 10 billions of times can add this overhead? Do you have any suggestion about the code to increase performance?

I am working in Windows environment and using the compiler vc14 of VisualStudio2015, with Boost 1.7.1. I observed a similar behaviour with gcc4.9 on a Linux machine, where the direct call to Boost takes 30s and the new class takes 45s.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Are you compiling in release mode?

Comment: Yes, with flag -O2

Comment: Do not know why you do not use `std::mt19937` (are you limited to C++03?), also I can't reproduce your problem [on gcc difference is minimal](http://quick-bench.com/7BFmGwOYITLF451hWRrUW93eYa8) [on clang no difference at all](http://quick-bench.com/GintTz7yTSy7hJvKjz79TX2_qMk).

Comment: @MarekR It's [minimal with `std`](https://godbolt.org/z/87Hzs8). But the difference in assembly with Boost [is significant](https://godbolt.org/z/KL3YGx). Can't understand why there is such an _instruction bloat_. I also suggest switching to `std::random`

Comment: I tried with std random generator, but in windows is slower than boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "some operations on registers I cannot explain" bit you highlighted:

```
00007FF6D1463B61  movsd       xmm3,mmword ptr [rbp+900h]  
00007FF6D1463B69  lea         rcx,[stduniform]  
00007FF6D1463B6E  movsd       xmm4,mmword ptr [rbp+8F8h]  
00007FF6D1463B76  movaps      xmm2,xmm3  
00007FF6D1463B79  mulsd       xmm2,xmm6  
00007FF6D1463B7D  movaps      xmm1,xmm4  
00007FF6D1463B80  mulsd       xmm1,xmm6  
00007FF6D1463B84  movaps      xmm0,xmm2  
00007FF6D1463B87  subsd       xmm0,xmm1  
00007FF6D1463B8B  comisd      xmm0,xmm7  
00007FF6D1463B8F  jbe         main+2F8h (07FF6D1463B98h)
```

seems to match up with the following lines in `generate_uniform_real`:

```
T result = numerator / divisor * (max_value - min_value) + min_value;
if(result < max_value) return result;
```

So it seems like the compiler is unable to inline the `min_value` and `max_value` arguments to this function.

For what it's worth, I could not reproduce a significant performance difference on:

- Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
- Boost 1.69.0_2

Comment: So, with the class, the compiler is actually inlining both the function `get()` and `real_(gen_)`? Whereas with the actual call to boost distribution, `real(gen)` is not inlined?

Comment: In both cases everything up to and including `detail::generate_uniform_real` is inlined. In the class case, however, the `min_value` and `max_value` parameters are taken from the `uniform_real_distribution` object, while in the unwrapped case these parameters are known at compile time. The former thus has to go through all these calculations at runtime, while the latter has resolved them at compile time.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. In fact, if I remove from the function `detail::generate_uniform_real` every reference to `min_value` and `max_value` I get the exact same performance between the two test cases. I need to figure out a way to make the compiler understand those values are known.

Comment: It _might_ be as easy as making the `real_` member `const` or `inline static`, but I cannot reproduce your issue so I cannot give well-tested advice ;)

Comment: Thanks @Botje, but I tried both way but there is no improvement, I even tried to make min_value and max_value template parameters of my class without any success. I checked with clang (v11) and there is no difference in performance, both cases took 50s, but on the very same machine, with g++ 9.2 the first test takes 25s, the second 36s. Is there a way that you can try on your machine with gcc? Thanks a lot. I compiled with `-std=c++11 -O3 -finline-functions`.

Comment: Indeed, I see a significant difference with g++ 9.2.0. Moving the definition of `real_` inside `get()` makes both perform the same.

Comment: Ok, I confirm it perfectly works on Linux but not on Windows..I'll keep trying different solutions. Thanks a lot @Botje!